# JQuery override element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 8 items in a list that on hover expand their content through this code(I post only code for one item)

```
(function($){
"use strict";
jQuery("#foto-chiara").click(function() {
    if($("#foto-chiara").css('top') == '0px'){
 $("#foto-chiara").stop().animate({top:$("#bio-chiara").height() +'px'},1000);
 }else{


 $("#foto-chiara").stop().animate({top:'0px'},1000);
 };
 $("#info-chiara").toggle(500);
 });


 }(jQuery));
```

The issue occur when an item in a first row expand and override the content of the item above. How can i prevent this?

Css code

```
#foto-chiara{
background-image:url("http://www.aspeera.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Chiara_foto1.png");width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute;top:0px;
}
#info-chiara{
display:none;
background-image:url("http://www.aspeera.it/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Chiara_fondo1.png");
width:200px;
height:150px;
position:absolute;
}
```

HTML code(Only one item)

```
<ul class="container_info">
    <li class="info-persone" id="bio-chiara" style="position:relative; height:300px;">
           <div id="foto-chiara">
           </div>
           <div id="info-chiara">
           <p>Chiara è una runner, questo dice molto di lei: tenace e con un'energia infinita. </p>
           </div>
    </li>
```

Comment: Can u include HTML code?

Comment: My suspects are that the elements are `absolute` positioned, but we need to see the HTML markup, and css styles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the element position to relative

```
position: relative
```

Comment: Why should the user do this? What is the purpose?

Comment: i'm developing a page for people who work in a project and they want the about us page in this way..